# L8 - HTTP Concurrent Requests - Confused building closure dynamically

Tags: php, http, request, closures, laravel-8

I'm testing the "Concurrent requests" feature:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#concurrent-requests

but I'm confused on how to create a closure input value dynamically.

For example I've an array:

```
$a = [
    'foo' => 'http//localhost/1',
    'bar' => 'http//localhost/2'
];
```

and I need to create, dynamically, something like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => [
    $pool->as('foo')->get('http://localhost/1'),
    $pool->as('bar')->get('http://localhost/2'),
]);

return $responses['foo']->body();
```

Updating `$a` the closure content should changes.
How I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$a = [
    'foo' => 'http//localhost/1',
    'bar' => 'http//localhost/2'
];

$fn2 = function (\Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool $pool) use ($a) {
    foreach ($a as $aKey => $aVal) {
        $arrayPools[] = $pool->as($aKey)->get($aVal);
    }
    return $arrayPools;
};
$responses = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::pool($fn2);

echo $responses['foo']->body();
```

Comment: You are a legend. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ->map()

```
$a = collect($a);
Http::pool(fn(Pool $pool) =>
        $a->map(fn($url) =>
            $pool->get($url->toArray[1])
));
```